# How to specify relationships using RestKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, rest, restkit

I'm trying to use RestKit to map some JSON to my Core Data entities.

I have a `Case` entity with  a `caseId` attribute and an optional one-to-many relationship to a `Binder` entity called `binders`. The `Binder` entity has an inverse one-to-one relationship to `Case` called `case` that's not optional.

I can successfully map the `Case` entities, but I'm having trouble with mapping the `Binder` entities.

My mappings are set up as follows:

```
RKEntityMapping *caseEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Case" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[caseEntityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:[@"caseId"]];

RKEntityMapping *binderEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Binder" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];


NSString *pathPattern = @"rest/case/list";

[router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithName:@"getCases" pathPattern:pathPattern method:RKRequestMethodGET]];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:caseEntityMapping pathPattern:pathPattern keyPath:@"data" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[_objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];


pathPattern = @"rest/binder/list/:caseId";

[router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithRelationshipName:@"binders" objectClass:[PFCase class] pathPattern:pathPattern method:RKRequestMethodGET]];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:binderEntityMapping pathPattern:pathPattern keyPath:@"data" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[_objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

I get the cases by using `[_objectManager getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:@"getCases" object:nil parameters:nil success:… failure:…]` and then inside the success block, I get the binders for each case by executing the request operation created using `[_objectManager requestWithPathForRelationship:@"binders" ofObject:mappedCase method:RKRequestMethodGET parameters:nil]`.

But there are no mapping results for the binders. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a foreign key RKConnectionDescription to the binder entity mapping, which required me to create a new attribute for the `Binder` entity called `caseId`.

Is there any way to do this without having to create a new attribute? Also, what is the key path RKConnectionDescription for/when would it be needed?